# Removing 5 seconds from a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, time, calculation

I'm hoping to pull a variable from a text box that would be submitted like "201442" turn it into time 20:14:42 then subtract 5 seconds for the output 20:14:37. So far i have:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>-5</title>
<script>
var incomingtime = "0";
</script>
<script>
    function calctime(){
  incomingtime = document.getElementById("inputtime").value;
  alert (incomingtime);
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="inputtime"/><input type="text" id="outputtime"/><br>
<button onclick="calctime()">-5 Dat</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What would be the best approach? Splitting up the input into three sections and doing the math that way? Or is there a simpler solution? How would i go about throwing first two chars into a variable, third and fourth into a var, then 5th and 6th into a var for calculations?

Comment: Moment.js is a beautiful library for stuff like this. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

Comment: Convert the input to a `Date` object, then use `d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds-5)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should parse your string and put your time into Date() object, then it will be easier to do any computations on your time value
You can parse it in the following way:

```
timeObj = new Date(0,0,0,
  incomingtime.substring(0, 2),
  incomingtime.substring(2, 4),
  incomingtime.substring(4, 6));
```

Then you can carry out your values, using object's 'get' functions.
If you want to change its value, you can just add or substract time (in miliseconds). For example, if you want to substract 5 seconds, you should just:

```
timeObj -= 5*1000;
```

Comment: If you're not going to provide a detailed code example, this should just be a comment. When you get enough reputation you'll be able to comment on other poster's questions.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean saying "detailed code example", I'm new to stackoverflow, so, I don't understand why I should put my answer as comment. I give an example of code with it's explanation, so, why it can't be considered as answer?